# Extra blank file showing up when running crontab -e

Tags: linux, centos, cron, centos6

On Centos 6.5 when I type crontab -e for my user I get 2 files split vertically instead of just one. The top file is blank and can't be saved as it is a new file. THe bottom file is my actual crontab.

You can see it here 
[image: https://imgur.com/GOScaxT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a setting in the `.vimrc` that would cause this? Something like

`au VimEnter * hsplit`

Comment: Looks like my .vimrc had something wrong with it. I am using this one [Ultimate Vimrc](http://amix.dk/vim/vimrc.txt). The newest version is working.